# How to use debounce stream based on value?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, reactive-extensions-js

For example, assume that we have stream like following

```
Stream 1 | -1-2-3-1-2-3--4-----------
```

after debounce, I would like to have the emitted stream looks like as follows:

```
Stream 2 | ---------------1-2-3--4------
```

There are lots of examples how to debounce the stream, but they take all value as the same trigger.

The following is the example code I found in reactitve-extension website,

```
var Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
var times = [
    { value: 1, time: 100 },
    { value: 2, time: 200 },
    { value: 3, time: 300 },
    { value: 1, time: 400 },
    { value: 2, time: 500 },
    { value: 3, time: 600 },
    { value: 4, time: 800 }
];

// Delay each item by time and project value;
var source = Rx.Observable.from(times)
  .flatMap(function (item) {
    return Rx.Observable
      .of(item.value)
      .delay(item.time);
  })
  .debounceTime(500 /* ms */);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

The console output would be

```
Next: 4
Completed
```

But I would like to get the following output

```
Next: 1
Next: 2
Next: 3
Next: 4
Completed
```

Maxime give good answer.
I also try myself. Hope help someone who have the same question.

```
var Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
var times = [
    { value: 1, time: 100 },
    { value: 2, time: 200 },
    { value: 3, time: 300 },
    { value: 1, time: 400 },
    { value: 2, time: 500 },
    { value: 3, time: 600 },
    { value: 4, time: 800 },
    { value: 5, time: 1500 }
];

// Delay each item by time and project value;
var source = Rx.Observable.from(times)
  .flatMap(function (item) {
    return Rx.Observable
      .of(item.value)
      .delay(item.time);
  })
  .do(obj => console.log('stream 1:', obj, 'at', Date.now() - startTime, `ms`))
  .groupBy(obj => obj)
  .flatMap(group => group.debounceTime(500))

let startTime = Date.now();
var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('stream 2: %s', x, 'at', Date.now() - startTime, 'ms');
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

The console will output

```
stream 1: 1 at 135 ms
stream 1: 2 at 206 ms
stream 1: 3 at 309 ms
stream 1: 1 at 409 ms
stream 1: 2 at 509 ms
stream 1: 3 at 607 ms
stream 1: 4 at 809 ms
stream 2: 1 at 911 ms
stream 2: 2 at 1015 ms
stream 2: 3 at 1109 ms
stream 2: 4 at 1310 ms
stream 1: 5 at 1510 ms
stream 2: 5 at 1512 ms
Completed
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want to get distinct values of all the items that were emitted only when no event occurs for a certain period of time?

Comment: Maxime give good answer.

Comment: Yes, I did, but it popup the console said that I have less 15 reputation that wouldn't change the vote count.

Comment: Once I get exceed 15 reputation, I will go back here to vote it again.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code I propose :

```
const { Observable } = Rx

const objs = [
  { value: 1, time: 100 },
  { value: 2, time: 200 },
  { value: 3, time: 300 },
  { value: 1, time: 400 },
  { value: 2, time: 500 },
  { value: 3, time: 600 },
  { value: 4, time: 800 }
];

const tick$ = Observable.interval(100)

const objs$ = Observable.from(objs).zip(tick$).map(x => x[0])

objs$
  .groupBy(obj => obj.value)
  .mergeMap(group$ => 
    group$
     .debounceTime(500))
  .do(obj => console.log(obj))
  .subscribe()
```

And the output is just as expected :

[image]

Here's a working Plunkr with demo
https://plnkr.co/edit/rEI8odCrhp7GxmlcHglx?p=preview

---

**Explanation :**

I tried to make a small schema :[image]

The thing is, you cannot use the `debounceTime` directly on the main observable (that's why you only had one value). You've got to group every values in their own stream with the `groupBy` operator and apply the `debounceTime` to the splitted group of values (as I tried to show in the image). Then use `flatMap` or `mergeMap` to get one final stream.

**Doc :**
Here are some pages that might help you understand :
 - [groupBy](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-groupBy)
 - [debounceTime](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime)
 - [mergeMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helps a lot. The sample code is clear and easy to understand.